# How to create Event Handler for DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in a Data Grid View in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in a data grid view. I have attached a list as a data source . Now i need to fire an event based on the selected index of the combobox..How can I go aboout doing it ?  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that the `SelectedIndex` property belongs to the editing control (which is only active when the `DataGridView` is in edit mode), you could attach an event handler to `EditingControlShowing` like so:

```
void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Control is ComboBox) {
        // remove handler first to avoid attaching twice
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectedIndexChanged -= MyEventHandler;
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).SelectedIndexChanged += MyEventHandler;
    }
}
```

Note that the actual type of the control is `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`, which extends `ComboBox`. You only need the functionality from the base class, plus it's less to type.