# Event that fires during DataGridViewComboBoxColumn SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have `DataGridView` with two columns. The first column is `TextBoxCol(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)` and the Second one is `ComboBoxCol(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)`.

How can I change the value of `TextBoxCol` when `ComboBoxCol` changes its selected index value?
(This should happen when selected index changed in `ComboBoxCol`. Not after leaving the column, like `dataGridView_CellValueChanged`)

I have read one topic with almost the same problem that I am having but I dont understand the answer(which should be correct base on the check mark). Here's the link. [-Almost same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154713/how-to-create-event-handler-for-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-in-a-data-grid-view-i)

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll keep an eye out for any more of your questions as I already have the project open :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What event catches a change of value in a combobox in a DataGridViewCell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652957/what-event-catches-a-change-of-value-in-a-combobox-in-a-datagridviewcell)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Give these two simple methods a go (the '1' in the top method is the index of the combobox column)

The line that you would make you modifications to would be the setter line `cel.Value =`, as you may change it to whatever you like.

---

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
        var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];
        cel.Value = sendingCB.EditingControlFormattedValue.ToString();
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: Make sure you also remove any existing event handlers with `comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;`

Answer (score 51):

This answer is floating around in a couple of places.

Using the DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler will fire more events than you intend.  In my testing it fired the event  multiple times.

Also using the combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= event will not really remove the event, they just keep stacking.

Anyway, I found a solution that seems to work. I'm including a code sample below:

```cs
// Add the events to listen for
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);



// This event handler manually raises the CellValueChanged event 
// by calling the CommitEdit method. 
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        // This fires the cell value changed handler below
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // My combobox column is the second one so I hard coded a 1, flavor to taste
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
    if (cb.Value != null)
    {
         // do stuff
         dataGridView1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: This really is better than the accepted solution. Only thing I had to change was adding if (e.RowIndex == -1)
                return; to the beginning of the dataGridView1_CellValueChanged function

Comment: Yep, definitely a better solution, the selected one fires the event multiple times.

Comment: Great answer, imho should be the accepted one!! Just one thing to add: Within the `CellValueChanged` handler you might wanna check which Column/Cell was changed instead of generally "doing stuff" ;-) E.g. `if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Column2"].Index) ...`

Comment: You must call DataGridView.BeginEdit() after committing the change in the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event handler to put the "focus" back on the EditingControl (the ComboBox) and really make this behave like the ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: This is the best solution for me. With a little tweaking to limit the selected cell and you have a less hassle to solve

Comment: That's the kind of voodoo .NET coders should include by default. It shouldn't be expected for a user to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

That link is correct. Handle the `EditingControlShowing event` of DataGridView. In this event handler, check if the current column is of your interest. And, then create a temporary combobox object :-

`ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;`

MSDN has a sample: See in the example section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx). 
**Note the** `Inheritance Hierarchy` & `Class Syntax` in the msdn link : -

> public class DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl : **ComboBox**, 
>     IDataGridViewEditingControl

```
private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

private void AddColorColumn()
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn =
        new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboBoxColumn.Items.AddRange(
        Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue);
    comboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(Color);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing +=
        new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(
        dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
}

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (combo != null)
    {
        // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid 
        // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=
            new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

        // Add the event handler. 
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=
            new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)sender).BackColor = (Color)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
}
```