# Combobox datagridview selection changed populate value in datagridview other cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcombobox

I want to populate the value in datagridview cell based on selection changed event of combo box which is residing inside the datagridview.

In the below screenshot I want to populate value in Area column based on selection change event of combobox data grid view.

[image]

Comment: Try the code of this question [DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is invalid with binded DataGridViewComboBoxCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854881/datagridviewcomboboxcell-valuevalue-is-invalid-with-binded-datagridviewcomboboxc/28874060#28874060)

Comment: Use [`CellValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
  Private DG_CellValueChanged(Object sender , DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    if(e.RowIndex.equls(-1))
       {
         return;
       }
    if(e.ColumnIndex.Equls(0))
      {    if(e.RowIndex.equls(-1))
           {
             return;
           }
        if(e.ColumnIndex.Equls(0))
          {
            string sVal=//Your Calculation  
            DG.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cell[1].value=sVal;
          }
        }
```

If U creating **DataGridViewComboBoxCell** object

```
  Private DG_CellValueChanged(Object sender , DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
            if(e.RowIndex.equls(-1))
               {
                 return;
               }
            if(e.ColumnIndex.Equls(0))
              {
                string sVal=//Your Calculation  
                DG.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cell[1].value=sVal;
              }
            }
```