# How to handle DataGridViewComboBox SelectedIndex Changed event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a One DataGridView it has Two DataGridViewComboBoxColumn i want to handle selectedindexchanged event of both differently

how can i achieve ?

IN Winform VB.net

Comment: I believe you can find your answers in other questions already asked, for example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141872/event-that-fires-during-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-selectedindexchanged).

Comment: i already go through this its work  fine with one combobox column but i have to combobox in datagridview and that not manged with this

Comment: I have TWO combobox in datagridview ....

Comment: See the example I posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to differentiate between which combobox-column was clicked by the columnindex. Small example:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
        If dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
            Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)

            'remove handler if it was added before
            RemoveHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ColumnCombo1SelectionChanged
            AddHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ColumnCombo1SelectionChanged
        ElseIf dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
            Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)

            'remove handler if it was added before
            RemoveHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ColumnCombo2SelectionChanged
            AddHandler cb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ColumnCombo2SelectionChanged
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ColumnCombo1SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sendingComboEdit = TryCast(sender, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
    Dim selectedValue As Object = sendingComboEdit.SelectedValue
End Sub

Private Sub ColumnCombo2SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sendingComboEdit = TryCast(sender, DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
    Dim selectedValue As Object = sendingComboEdit.SelectedValue
End Sub
```